# "...more I do something more..." Construction

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

I want to write some message about some programming language.

> The more I write a code on "language name" the more it's pleased to me.

Is this sentence correct? How I should say it correctly?

Comment: The more code I write in Python, the more it pleases me.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but there are some errors. If I were you, I would have written 'the more I code X the more it pleases me'.

Comment: I prefer *code **in** SomeLanguage* to *code SomeLanguage*, personally.  I reserve the latter syntax for things like *coding a new game engine*.

Comment: I'd combine the comments of both Jim and snailboat. First, the proper prepositional phrase--I believe in both BrE and AmE--would be ***in** language name*. Second, I prefer it with a comma separating the clauses, but comma usage is subjective. I'd also consider **not** using the present perfect here. I'm not sure about BrE, but AmE would call for the simple present tense (*the more it **pleases** me*)

Answer (score 2):

Putting the notes from the comments together, it appears that we recommend

> The more I code in (language-name), the more it pleases me.